# After logging in multiple time to salesforce account through IE Browser user account is locked and no unlock button is shown to unlock

Tags: login-errors

One of our user is creating BOT for Business purpose which tries to login into salesforce and it asks for verification code and then login into Salesforce. After Few attempts of login to salesforce we are getting a message "We cant send you a verification code right now. Please try again later".

I have added the IP Address of BOT SF Account to Trusted IP Ranges in Our Org, still issue is occurring. BOT is using IE 11 browser to login and access data. We also tried to set configuration in IE browser to make sure it supports to login to Salesforce.

Again the same issue is occurring after few login attempts even with correct credentials it is givng message as shown below[image]

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue to login into salesforce without getting locked even after multiple attempts to login into sal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Salesforce Knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317627&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1)

**Please wait an hour after the first of the 5 attempts, and request another code. Note: Salesforce has a limit of 5 SMS/email verification codes per hour** and also please check below.

**SMS (Text Message) Verification**

1. Fully reboot or restart the mobile device to refresh the device’s Carrier connection.
2. **If you receive the following error, please wait an hour after the first of the 5 attempts, and request another code. Note: Salesforce has a limit of 5 SMS verification codes per hour.**

Error Message: 'We can't send you a verification code right now. You may have attempted too many verifications in the last hour. Try again later.' 
Example: If a SMS Verification Code is requested at 9:00am, then again at 9:05, 9:15, 9:20, and 9:30 respectively, the next code would not send until after 10:00am.

**Email verification**

1. Check all Spam, Junk, or Clutter folders for the email. The email is sent from 'noreply@salesforce.com'and many email clients filter emails from no reply addresses.
2. Have your IT/Networking team whitelist all Salesforce IPs and Domains in this article What are the Salesforce IP Addresses & Domains to whitelist?
3. **If you receive the following error, please wait an hour after the first of the 5 attempts, and request another code. Note: Salesforce has a limit of 5 email verification codes per hour**.

Error Message: 'We can't send you a verification code right now. You may have attempted too many verifications in the last hour. Try again later.'
Example: If an email Verification Code is requested at 9:00am, then again at 9:05, 9:15, 9:20, and 9:30 respectively, the next code would not send until after 10:00am.

If you need immediate access, and the above steps did not work, you may use these workarounds:

1. An administrator may add your IP address to the Trusted IP list under Setup | Security Controls | Network Access. To learn how, please review Set Trusted IP Ranges for Your Organization.
2. If you are not getting the code via email, and you have SMS verification enabled in your org, you may have an administrator add a mobile number to send the code via SMS (Text Message). To learn how, please review How to verify a valid mobile number.

Note: If the above troubleshooting steps do not resolve your issue, please file a case with Salesforce Support